# Can I add values of a list to a spring applicationContext.xml property?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am very new to spring and I am currently working on a program someone else has written years ago. Basically, the program is sending emails to a group that is referenced in the applicationContext.xml file as groupA.
Now I retrieve other emails addresses I would like emails to be sent to as well.
How can I tell spring to consider my new group (which is a list of emails called contactList) in addidition to groupA when sending emails?

```
<bean id="myClass"
    class="com.myClass">
    <property name="emailAddressFrom"
        value="dev" />
    <property name="emailAddressTo"
        value="groupA" />
</bean>
```

here is where I create the list in my code and get the values.

```
List<String> contactList = contact.getEmailAddress(Dept_Code);
```

Comment: Is the new group also declared in the Spring context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can and its very simple.

```
<bean id="myClass"
    class="com.myClass">
  <property name="contactList">
     <list>
      <value>email1</value>
      <value>email2</value>
      <value>email3</value>
     </list>
   <property>
</bean>
```

For asked question in comment not sure where to add this but I am adding here. You can pass 1 list to other as constructor argument. Somthing like this:

```
<bean id="stages" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg ref="stages1" />       
</bean>

<bean id="stages1" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="stage1" />
            <ref bean="stage2" />                
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: If we assume `groupA` is a list in itself. How do you concatenate that list with the new one?

Comment: that is what I am trying to figure out @SotiriosDelimanolis. I don't know much about spring and would like to know how to keep groupA and add a new list.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you want now. Updating again answer soon.

Comment: With this solution I am supposed to know the values of contactList. contacList is just a container and the values may be different at every run.. So email1, email2 etc. may not be the same all the time.

Answer (score 1):

in you class,

```
private List<String> emailAddressTo = new ArrayList<String>();

public void setEmailAddressTo(String email){
    this.emailAddressTo.add(email);
    List<String> contactList = contact.getEmailAddress(Dept_Code);
    emailAddressTo.add(contactList);

}
```

Now your emailAddressTo list have the spring injected as well as programmatically loaded contactList.